# When does the Community user create a tag?

Tags: support, tags, community-user

I noticed that the Community user can create tags. For example, the Community user [created](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5022378/1) the [ubuntu tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ubuntu/info) on Stack Overflow.
When does the Community user create a tag?